# Count all occurrences of a character except at the end of the string

Tags: java, regex

For example

```
String text = "sentence";     // (number of e's = 2)
```

There are three e's in that string, but the result should be `2` because the third one is at the very end.  This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count =0;
    String text    = "sentence";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[e]+");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: You could apply the regex on a substring without the last character

Comment: Do you have to use regex? This task seams to be to be better suited to a simple loop.

Comment: Can you explain how to use.I need to count e's in middle but should not count that e  when it  is last character in the word.

Comment: What is wrong with the code posted?

Comment: @mlk i need to use regex

Comment: It shows number of e's as 3 i.e.., it counts the last e in given text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `+`  which exists after `e` with  negative lookahead. `e+` matches one or more `e`'s , so regex engine should consider `eee` as single match. And a negative lookahead after `e`, ie `e(?!$)` helps to find all the `e`'s but not the one which exists at the end of a line.

```
int count = 0;
String text = "sentence";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("e(?!$)");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
        count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Worked fine.Can you explain how

Comment: @JagadeeshSinde `(?!x)` is a negative look-ahead, meaning, "not followed by `x`". In this case, `x` is `$`, which matches the end-of-text, so in full it means, "an `e` that is not followed by end-of-text.

Comment: If input text has multiple words will it work.Example input: String text ="sentence are the"(Output should be 2).Code is not working for this type of input.

Comment: @JagadeeshSinde You said "except if the `e` that is last character in the given **text**", not last character in *word*. `"sEntEncE arE the"`. 4 e's, not counting last one. But if you want last-in-word semantics, replace the `$` with `\\b` (word-boundary), as in `"e(?!\\b)"`: An `e` that is not followed by a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

`Matcher` methods can tell you the start and end index of the match. If end (next character after) matches the length of the string then it's the last character. E.g.

```
int count =0;
String text = "sentence";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("e");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
while (m.find() && m.end() != text.length()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

If you would like to exclude from counting last letter of a word instead of last word of the sentence, you can check whether the end character is alpha :

```
int count =0;
String text = "sentence";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("e");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
while (m.find() &&
       m.end() != text.length() &&
       Character.isAlphabetic(text.charAt(m.end()))) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Will only count 1 for `beet`, and will count 0 for `bee`. They are supposed to be 2 and 1, respectively.

Comment: that's actually a problem with `[e]+` it will match consecutive `e` only once. Just remove the `+`. I'll edit

Comment: In a comment to the now-accepted answer, OP changed requirements to exclude `e` at end-of word, not end-of-text. Don't you just love(!) changing requirements?

Comment: @Andreas It keeps people on their toes ;-)